# R: count occurrence by group until a specific year

Tags: r

A dataframe with the columns "country" and "year" may look like this:

```
nobel <- data.frame("country" = c("Japan", "USA", "Romania", "Russia", "USA", "USA"), "year" = c(2008, 1934, 2014, 1904, 2021, 1977))
```

What is the easiest way to find out how often country X appeared until (and including) a given year? For example, how often did Japan appear until 2013? How often did USA appear until 2020?

In fact, I have second dataframe, `nobel2`, which contains similar rows, like this:

```
nobel2 <- data.frame("country" = c("Japan", "USA", "Romania", "USA", "USA", "Angola"), "year" = c(2008, 2008, 2008, 2020, 2021, 2023))
```

I wanted to create a new column, `nobel2$nobel_nr`, which counts the number of occurrences of a country in `nobel` until that given year.

**Expected results**:

```
# =====================================
# country     | year      | nobel_nr  |
# =====================================
# Japan       | 2008      | 1         |
# USA         | 2008      | 2         |
# Romania     | 2008      | 0         |
# USA         | 2020      | 2         |
# USA         | 2021      | 3         |
# Angola      | 2023      | 0         |
# =====================================
```

**Attempt so far**:

I tried with the following (using dplyr), but it did not work:

```
nobel2 %>%
  mutate(nobel_nr = nobel %>% 
           filter(country == country & year <= year) %>% 
           count() %>% 
           as.numeric())
```

Comment: Try `nobel %>% filter(year <= 2020) %>% summarize(count = n(), .by = country)` or alternatively `nobel %>% filter(year <= 2020) %>% count(country)` - these should get your expected results (if you change 2020 to 2021). Th benefit of `summarize` is you can easily rename the column whatever you want (`count()` defaults to "n")

Comment: Please be more precise what the expected result is.

Comment: @s_baldur: Ok, I changed the original post. ||| jpsmith: Thanks for your help; I probably was not precise enough though; see the edited post.

Comment: Typo in line 3 of expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(nobel)
setDT(nobel2)

nobel2[, nobel_nr := nobel[.SD, on = .(country, year <= year), .N, by = .EACHI]$N]

> nobel2
#    country  year nobel_nr
#     <char> <num>    <int>
# 1:   Japan  2008        1
# 2:     USA  2008        2
# 3: Romania  2008        0
# 4:     USA  2020        2
# 5:     USA  2021        3
# 6:  Angola  2023        0
```